# Creating a flat tar file holding every filename in directory starting with "a"

Tags: linux, bash, centos7, tar, glob

I am using a command terminal inside a VirtualBox CentOS 7 linux system. I am attempting to create a tar file into a seperate directory that contains all the files in my current directory that start with the letter "a".

I have tried `tar -cvf fileName.tar /newDirectory ls a*` but I think that I'm doing something wrong. I assume this should only take one line of the command terminal to execute, does anybody know the right way to do it?

Comment: I am able to create the tar file within the same directory by "tar -cvf fileName.tar ls a*" but I don't know how to create it within a parent directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter is the tar file name (full path) and the second is the files you want take. Try it:

```
tar -cvf newDirectory/fileName.tar a*
```

Comment: Thanks! I read some misleading posts, but that works perfectly!